# IsChecked' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox

I have a form with tab page containing several checkboxes.

I need to loop through these checkboxes to see which ones are checked. From there, I need to grab the `.Tag` property so that I can in turn add a property with that name from another object to t list.

I have a problem with my code though. For the line -

```
DirectCast(objCtrl, CheckBox).IsChecked
```

I'm getting the error

> IsChecked' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'

This seems odd, as I obviously need to use that method to check if the checkbox is actually checked, and the docs seem to suggest that method exists.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
Dim objCtrl As Control
For Each objCtrl In Me.objConfigForm.tabPageGeneral.Controls
    If TypeOf objCtrl Is CheckBox AndAlso DirectCast(objCtrl, CheckBox).IsChecked Then

        Dim strProp As String = DirectCast(objCtrl, CheckBox).Tag
        arrGeneral.Add(objUser.strProp)

    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are looking at the documentation for [WPF CheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not to the docs for [WinForms Checkbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In the latter the property is named `Checked`

Answer (score 3):

The Property you want is `Checked` not IsChecked

See the help for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The property is Checked, not IsChecked.